# How to control trigger job from UI

Tags: java, jsf, triggers, richfaces, seam

I am using Seam 2.1.2 integrated with JSF, JPA and RichFaces.

In my application I am using `QuartzTriggerHandle` and I need to control `Trigger` from UI. How should I do this from user interface?

Sample code:

```
@Override
public String triggerCustomerMigration() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(2040, Calendar.MAY, 10);
    QuartzTriggerHandle customerHandler = asyncCustomerScheduler
        .scheduleCustomerMigration(new Date(), "0 0/6 * * * ?", cal.getTime());
    return customerHandler.getTrigger().getName();
} 

@Asynchronous
@Transactional
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public QuartzTriggerHandle scheduleCustomerMigration(@Expiration Date when,
    @IntervalCron String cron, @FinalExpiration Date endDate) 
{
    QuartzTriggerHandle handle = new QuartzTriggerHandle(
    SystemJobs.MIGRATE_CUSTOMER.getJobName());
    PersistenceProvider.instance().setFlushModeManual(getEntityManager());
}
```

Comment: I don't know about how to start a trigger in Quartz, but I know that when you call the action from an UICommand (`<h:commandButton>`, `<h:commandLink>`, etc.) then you can call any of your defined methods.

Comment: @Ant4res: "Seam", "JSF", "JPA" and "RichFaces" are **not** code. They are library/framework names. Please don't format library/framework names as code!

Comment: thanx Luiggi ,but i need how to start trigger in Quartz from UserInterface

Comment: @nag Do you need to trigger the event based on user interaction or some non-user related process on the client side?

Comment: @kolossue i need to start the triggerCustomerMigration() through the GUI and when its end i need stop processing through button.

Comment: @kolossue i was started this trigger from GUI using command button ,it is working good.i mention endDate is 2040 ,but i need to stop this trigger when ever if any failure  cases .could you give any suggestion how to stop trigger from GUI.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza can you tell me about  How to Stop QuartzTriggerHandle ?